# Having problems excluding tests from TestNG

Tags: java, methods, testng

I have the following TestNG Java class:

```
public class TestSequence {

    @BeforeTest
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Inside initialize...............");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group1", "group2" })
    public void commonCase() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside commonCase...............");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group1"}, dependsOnMethods = { "commonCase" })
    public void group1A() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside group1A...............");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group1"}, dependsOnMethods = { "group1A" })
    public void group1B() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside group1B...............");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group1"}, dependsOnMethods = { "group1B" })
    public void group1C() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside group1C...............");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group1"}, dependsOnMethods = { "group1C" })
    public void group1D() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside group1D...............");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group2"}, dependsOnMethods = { "commonCase" })
    public void group2A() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside group2A...............");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group2"}, dependsOnMethods = { "group2A" })
    public void group2B() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside group2B...............");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group2"}, dependsOnMethods = { "group2B" })
    public void group2C() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside group2C...............");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "group2"}, dependsOnMethods = { "group2C" })
    public void group2D() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside group2D...............");
    }
}
```

Here is the testng.xml that I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestSequence">
        <methods>
            <include name="group1*"/>
            <exclude name="group2*"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I am running the test automation from the command line as follows:

```
java -cp C:\TestProject\lib\*;C:\TestProject\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

The output that I get is as follows:

```
Inside initialize...............
Inside commonCase...............
Inside group1A...............
Inside group2A...............
Inside group1B...............
Inside group2B...............
Inside group1C...............
Inside group2C...............
Inside group1D...............
Inside group2D...............
```

Why are group2 test cases not excluded despite the exclusion noted in the testng.xml?

Thanks much for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) says:

> Note: TestNG uses regular expressions, and not wildmats. Be aware of
>   the difference (for example, "anything" is matched by ".*" -- dot star
>   -- and not "*").

So, try changing:

```
    <methods>
        <include name="group1*"/>
        <exclude name="group2*"/>
    </methods>
```

By:

```
    <methods>
        <include name="group1.*"/>
        <exclude name="group2.*"/>
    </methods>
```